# Qt - How to do what I want when another dialog is closed?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I have two classes `A` and `B`, here is a snippet in `B.h`:

```
#include "A.h"
class B : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void do_something();
private:
    A *a;
}
```

and in `B.cpp`:

```
B::B(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::B)
{
    a = new A();
    a.show();
}
```

So what should I do if I want to call `do_something()` when the `ui` of `A` is closed (by pressing `Alt-F4`, for example) ?  Seems the  way of `signal-slot` cannot apply here.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: what is the type of `A`? QWidget or QDialog?

Comment: @UmNyobe both dialog. btw, how does it matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Modify class A to emit signal when closed

If modifying the A widget is option, add a signal to it and override `closeEvent` or `hideEvent` and emit the new signal there. This is robust and you have complete control on what happens. However, rest of the answer is for case where, for whaever reason, you are unable or unwilling to mess with A and want a solution in class B.

### Use the Qt signal for QObject deletion

If you can set [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) on `A`, then simple way is to make `B::doSomething()` (note the common Qt method naming convention) a slot and connect [`destroyed` signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#destroyed) of A instance to that.

```
B::B(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::B)
{
    a = new A();
    a->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    connect(a, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), SLOT(doSomething()));
    a.show();
}
```

Of course this works even if you `delete a;` explicitly, and not automatically with the attribute.

*Note:* In this case, when the object may get deleted whenever, you should really use [`QPointer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qpointer.html) for the `a` pointer, to avoid accidentally referencing a dangling pointer.

### Use Qt event filter

If you don't want to have the A instance deleted when it is closed (and re-created if it is needed again), then other way is to install event filter on the A instance, and detect the [`closeEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#closeEvent). This has the potential problem, that the widget can reject the close event, and in any case `doSomething` is called before the closing. If this is a problem, it can be solved by using [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod` static method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to delay the `doSomething` (it must be slot or invokable method for this!) call to happen after close event is over and program returns to event loop. Then in `doSomething` check if `a` is really hidden. Instead of `QEvent::Close`, detecting `QEvent::Hide` might work well, too.

To implement this, override the virtual [`eventFilter` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#eventFilter) in B, something like this:

```
bool B::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Close) { //or QEvent::Hide maybe
        qDebug("QCloseEvent!");

        // check that object is indeed this->a before calling this->doSomething()
        if (qobject_cast<QObject *>(a) == obj) {
            doSomething();
            //alternative, make doSomething to be called later from event loop:
            //QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doSomething", Qt::QueuedConnection);
        } else {
            qDebug("...but the object is not what is expected, a bug?");
        }
        // do not block the event, just detect it
    }

    // proceed with standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Then start listening events of an `A` instance with [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#installEventFilter), something like:

```
B::B(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::B)
{
    a = new A();
    installEventFilter(a);
    a.show();
}
```

Comment: The event filter solution has a critical flaw: doSomething is called before closing A, and it's also called if A ignores the event and thus stays open. The proper way is emitting a signal from A when it accepts the closeEvent. (Also there's a differnce between hiding and closing; accepting a close will hide a widget).

Comment: @peppe I wouldn't call that a critical flaw, as it depends on what *doSomething* does, and if the actual widget even has the code to reject the close event. Anyway, workaround for that would be to invoke *doSomething* via event loop, and test if *a* is indeed hidden (or deleted...). But still, good point! I'll improve the answer later.

Comment: @yakiang Answer edited after peppe's comment, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use a modal window (or dialog) than you have a little more work, you'll need to subclass QWidget (or QDialog or other QWidget derived class, whatever you need) and override [QWidget::closeEvent](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#closeEvent) (for class *A*) and from here call a method of the parent (i suppose *a* will be a child of *this* in your code: *a = new A(this);*) or code your own signal/slot.

And if you decide to use a modal dialog, the code becomes simpler, see example code in the QDialog's [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qdialog.html#details).

Answer (score 0):

The `QDialog::finished(int)` signal is *probably sufficient* to find out when a dialog has been closed.

There are ways to hide a dialog without `finished` being emitted, but they don't come up in typical `QDialog` usage.